# How to Compute the answer to the following limit problems?

Tags: calculus, limits

According to the answers in my book e = 4 and b = -2, I am unsure about e, but for b I would have assumed it to be -1.

**Can someone explain to me why the answers are what they are?**

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: For $a$, you see that $f(x)$ tends to $-2$ when $x$ tends to $2^-$ and $f(x)$ tends to $2$ when $x$ tends to $2^+$ : squaring, you obtain that $f^2(x)$ tends to $4$ when $x$ tends to $2$. For $b$, use continuity : when $x$ tends to $0$, then $f(x)$ tends to $2$ (being $<2$), so the limit of $f(f(x))$ when $x$ tends to $0$ is the same as the limit of $f(x)$ when $x$ tends to $2^-$, which is as you can see, equal to $-2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x\to2$, $f(x)$ tends to $-2$ on the left and $+2$ on the right, hence the square tends to $4$ on both sides, and this is the limit (the value at $x=2$ is irrelevant).

Then the limit of $f$ at $x=0$ is $2$, and more precisely $2^-$ because the values remain smaller than $2$. As seen above, the limit of $f$ on the left is $-2$.

Comment: I dont understand the: "As seen above, the limit of  on the left is −2." on the x axis or y axis? If on the y axis, isn't the value null thus it could only be -1?

Comment: @Outsider: as in the first sentence.

Answer (score 3):

(e): we have $\lim_{x \to 2-0}f(x)=-2$, hence $\lim_{x \to 2-0}f(x)^2=4$.

Furthermore: $\lim_{x \to 2+0}f(x)=2$, hence $\lim_{x \to 2+0}f(x)^2=4$.

This gives: $\lim_{x \to 2}f(x)^2=4$.

(b) we have $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)=2$ and $f(x)<2$ for $x \in (-1,1) \setminus \{0\}.$

Hence $\lim_{x \to 0}f(f(x))= \lim_{z \to 2-0}f(z)=-2.$